# Spring Security - Invalid property 'principal' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken]

Tags: spring-security, principal

I had to implement a custom "authentication provider" for a project, but I ran into troubles when trying to acces the Authentication's object properties in JSP. Details:
My custom authentication provider successfully creates an Authentication object

```
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, getAuthorities(userRoles));
log.info("User is authenticated");
return auth;
```

(Only relevant code here)

Then, in the controller method, I just display a log message with the username (this proves that the Authentication object is created and placed in the security context):

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();        
log.info("Welcoming user " + auth.getPrincipal());
```

Then in the JSP page I want to display the user name using

```
<sec:authentication property="principal"/>
```

However, this raises an error 500:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'principal' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken]: Bean property 'principal' is not readable...
```

I also noticed that

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="role">...
```

is not working, although the user has the necessary roles added in the Authentication object.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? The authentication works fine, I just can't access the authentication object's properties.

Thank you very much and have a good day.

Comment: What version of Spring Framework and Spring Security do you use?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that - Spring Framework 3.1.0 and Spring Security 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that I can't see anything wrong with your case, I think it can be [SPR-8347](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8347) bug, which is fixed in Spring 3.1.1. Can you do an upgrade?

Comment: Yey! Upgrading *both* Spring Security and Spring Framework to 3.1.2 worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!
However, the <sec:authorize /> problem still persist. The user has the necessary roles but the fragment within the <sec:authorize /> tag does not display...

Comment: Solved that, turned out to be an error between the keyboard and the chair - I had a " " at the end of the role name.

Answer (score 2):

your AuthenticationProvider must return UserDetails object.

From spring documentation
This tag allows access to the current Authentication object stored in the security context. It renders a property of the object directly in the JSP. So, for example, **if the principal property of the Authentication is an instance of Spring Security's UserDetails object, then using  will render the name of the current user.**

Comment: Deepak, **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken** implements **Authentication**, so everything is correct. The only difference is that you have to use

    <sec:authentication property="principal"/>

instead of 

   <sec:authentication property="user.principal"/>

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I think that I can help other folks.

As the first parameter of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken you may send a User.

Instead of passing the username, pass the user itself. But the user must be a class that extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails:

```
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, getAuthorities(userRoles));
log.info("User is authenticated");
return auth;
```

See the method that you was using:

```
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(authorities);
        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        super.setAuthenticated(true); // must use super, as we override
    }
```

Now, in yout tamplete, um can use something like this:

```
<span class="hidden-sm-down" sec:authentication="principal.email">Email</span>
```